# PATH variable not updating in Spyder

Tags: linux, environment-variables, conda, importerror, environment

first, I'll describe the problem. then I'll describe what I've tried. note that I am a novice in working with environment variables.

**the problem**:
In Spyder, I get a "module not found error" from certain libraries I've installed via pip, including tables and tensorflow. However, in Visual Studios these modules are successfully imported.

**what I've tried**

1. inspecting the directories the VS environment looks in, then adding these to $PATH in  Spyder via the PYTHONPATH manager. To determine the directories VS looks in, I typed "echo $PATH" in the VS terminal emulator. I got a list of paths (see below). I then went to Spyder and added each of these paths via the PYTHONPATH manager.
2. found the locations of "tensorflow" by searching for "tensorflow" in Finder.  I then went to Spyder and added each of these paths in PYTHONPATH manager.

**outcome: PYTHONPATH and PATH do not change**
In the terminal emulator in Spyder, I check to see if PYTHONPATH and PATH are updated but they are not.

in the python terminal emulator, this is the output:

```
!echo $PYTHONPATH
/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources

!echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

For reference, in the VS terminal emulator the PATH and PYTHONPATH variables are as follows:

```
(base) rahel-gerson:~ rahelmizrahi$ echo $PYTHONPATH

(base) rahel-gerson:~ rahelmizrahi$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Users/rahelmizrahi/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/rahelmizrahi/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Users/anaconda3/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

parsed version:
note that I couldn't find some of these paths, like "/anaconda3/bin:". Perhaps I parsed the list incorrectly? (I thought that after a colon is a new path)

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:
/Users/rahelmizrahi/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/rahelmizrahi/opt/anaconda3/condabin:
/Users/anaconda3/bin:
/anaconda3/bin:
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

Comment: Do you understand that environment variables are private to each process? That is, once a process is started you cannot change its env vars by changing the value in a different process?

Comment: hi, Kurtis. I am a beginner with processes and environment variables. also, can you explain how I am changing environment variables in a different process?

Comment: You cannot change the env vars of a different process without the cooperation of that process. And very few programs provide a mechanism for doing so.

Comment: how am I doing that, though? if you could look at my post and tell me, which of  the steps I took constitutes changing the env vars of a different process without the cooperation of that process, that would be helpful.

Comment: I have no idea how the VisualStudio embedded terminal works but if your starting the VS terminal after changing the VS env vars then that is a new "process" and would inherit the changed env vars from VS. Ignore VS and Spyder for a moment. Start two terminals outside of either of those programs. It doesn't matter if its Konsole, xterm, or something else. Examine the value of PATH in each one. They should be the same. Now change PATH in one of those terminals and examine the value in the other terminal. It will be unchanged. That's just how env vars work in UNIX like operating systems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236275/discussion-between-kurtis-rader-and-rahel-miz).